# How do I write a python script to read through files in a Linux directory and perform certain actions?

Tags: python-3.x, file, unix, terminal

I need to write a python script to read through files in a directory, retrieve the header record (which contains date)? I need to compare the date in the header record of each file with current date and if the difference is greater than 30 days. I need to delete such files.
I managed to come up with below code but not sure how to proceed since I am new to Python.

Example:

```
Sample file in the directory (/tmp/ah): abcdedfgh1234.123456
Header record : FILE-edidc40: 20200602-123539     46082 /tmp/ah/srcfile
```

I have below code for the list of files in the current directory. I need to pass the python equivalent of below actions on unix files

```
head -1 file|cut -c 15-22 
Output: 20200206 (to compare with current date and if older than 30) then delete file(using rm command).
```

```
import os

def files in os.listdir(path):
     for files in os.listdir(path):
         if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,file)):
             yield file

     for file in files(".")  : # prints the list of files
```

Comment: See [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python) for how to read a file. Why did you tag the question with _shell_? I don't see anything related to POSIX shell in your question.

Comment: Thanks I will go through that. I have also removed the tag.